# Oracle ORA-01029, Entity Framework Select VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, oracle11g, odac

I'm getting the following error when I try to get some data.

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-01029: internal two task error at 
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck) at 
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck) at 
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Read() at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()

This is the code I'm using

```
Using ctx As New EntidadIncap
   Dim query = From i In ctx.INCAPACIDADES
               Where i.INCAPACIDAD_ID = IncapacidadId
               Select i

   Dim incap As INCAPACIDADES = query.FirstOrDefault() 'Here I get the mentioned error.

   'code goes on...
End Using
```

And here is the "weird" part, this code works like 2 or 3 times before the ORA-01029 comes into scene.
I tried deleting the entity model and making a new one, it didn't work, I still get the error.
Once I get this error I can't make it go away until I drop the table and recreate it, then everything works fine.

I think the table goes corrupt, or something like that.
Some insight would be great, thanks.

Comment: That is some strange internal error.  What does the actual generated SQL look like?

Comment: @OldProgrammer It looks like this SELECT 
"Extent1"."INCAPACIDAD_ID" AS "INCAPACIDAD_ID", 
"Extent1"."CODIGO_INCAPACIDAD" AS "CODIGO_INCAPACIDAD", 
"Extent1"."TIPO_CENTRO_ID" AS "TIPO_CENTRO_ID", 
"Extent1"."FECHA_EXPEDICION" AS "FECHA_EXPEDICION"
FROM "INCAP"."INCAPACIDADES" "Extent1"
WHERE (55 = "Extent1"."INCAPACIDAD_ID")